# Sass/Less/etc based gridsystem?

Tags: css, sass, less

I've previously used 960.gs for grids in my designs. It's worked great. But the amounts of classes in the html is a bit tedious, and because I'm a web-purist, it's always felt a bit wrong to control styling in the markup.

I'm trying to find a good solution that adds the same functionality as 960.gs But without all the extra classes, by using som clever sass/less/etc.

Comment: [sussy grid](http://susy.oddbird.net/) is worth looking at.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're looking for is [semantic.gs](http://semantic.gs/).

It emphasises a grid with semantic markup with no need for `.spanX` etc. in the HTML.

I've written an adaptation of it in stylus (their stylus implementation isn't very good), so if you use stylus I'll be happy to give you a copy.

Answer (score 0):

It will have a bit of a learning curve after 960, but I have had good experience with http://framelessgrid.com/ example (responsive) build with it www.hardyamies.com

It is available as both LESS and SASS. The key concept is to use column variables for widths in the css. Meaning you can stay semantic with your naming.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend http://semantic.gs/

No extra classes in your HTML needed, fluid or fixed layout, works in LESS, SCSS and Stylus.